# Why doesn't a PHP string "<>" show up in echo?

Tags: php, string

I have a question with regards to what happens to a PHP string enclosed within two <> symbols? For example, I have a string, `"This is an <apple>"`. When I tried to `echo` the string, the result is "This is an".

So my question is: what happens to the string enclosed within the symbols?

To provide some context, I'm using this as a placeholder for a regex search and replace in my code.

I'm also using PHP 5.3 at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: **<** and **>** are HTML. Your browser think you has output an HTML-Element. Encode it with **htmlspecialchars([$string = ""]);** or use **&lt;** and **&gt;**.

Comment: Because in `HTML`, tags as hidden. Even invalid tags. Either add them in a `<pre>` element, or `echo htmlspecialchars($string);`.

Comment: Besides the answer(s) given, you can use `echo htmlentities("This is an <apple>");` However if you want the quotes to also appear, you would do `echo htmlentities('"This is an <apple>"');`

Comment: Appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has got nothing to do with php, but with html. Your browser thinks you are using an html tag.

To avoid that, you need to encode the characters:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('This is an <apple>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your browser interprets `<Apple>` as a HTML tag.  Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead